# Read the last delta partition without read all the delta

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I need to read automatically a delta file and I need to read only the last partition that was created. All the delta is big. The delta is partitioned by **yyyy** and **mm**

```
val df = spark.read.format("delta").load("url_delta").where(s"yyyy=${yyyy} and mm=${mm}")
```

I need to know the values of **yyyy** year and **mm** month. Is not efficient read all the delta and filter it bt the `max("yyyy")` and the `max("mm")`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you partition on yyyy and mm, then getting the max year and month will be a metadata only operation and just look at the transaction log, so it should be really quick.